# How to solve this issue in QT creator5.5.1?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

When i run my first project in QT creator 5.5.1 and then it appears this in Issue  "Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in the kit options." and in output it appears "21:12:35: Configuration is faulty. Check the Issues view for details.
Error while building/deploying project Bunthai (kit: Desktop)
When executing step "Make" ".

Comment: You need to chose a compiler (and possibly install it first), typical choices on Windows would be MSVC or mingw. You’re setting up a C++ though, your tags suggest that you want to you python, i.e. pyqt?

Comment: Thank you !! it works !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only installed Qt Creator, which is only an IDE, but does not contain any compiler or library.

Install the integrated suite instead : http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/

Under windows, it includes a preconfigured compiler (MinGW)

Comment: @Bun: I see you are new to stackoverflow. When an answer solves your problem, you can flag it as accepted - http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers